# Create a new item and add it to my neighbours's lists

Tags: netlogo

I would like to ask how I can add an element created by one turtle to its own list and its neighbour's lists. 
I created a local variable, `neighbours`, defined as `turtle-set in-link-neighbors with [breed=breed1]`. Then I asked neighbours to add the element created (new_elem), following an answer provided me by an user in this forum.

The code is:

```
to create_elements
 create-elements 1[
    set person one-of turtles with [breed = breed1 or breed = breed2]
    ifelse [breed = breed1] of person
    [
      set attribute1 random-float 1
      set attribute2 random-float 1

      set function1 (1 + attribute1)
    ]
    [
      set attribute1 random-float 1
      set attribute2 random-float 1

      set function2 (1 - attribute1)
    ]

  let neighbours (turtle-set self in-link-neighbors with [breed = breed1] of person)
      ask neighbours
      [set my-list fput new_elem my-list]
    ]
  ]
end
```

I know that there is an error in `let neighbours (turtle-set self in-link-neighbors with [breed = breed1] of person)...`, but also in putting an element in the list, as I think the new element is defined in the breed `elements`. In fact, the error message says that

> elements breed does not own variable my-list

Would it be possible to specify the breed of the `turtle-set`? What I would need is consider only `breed1` and `breed2`, not `elements` breed.
For example, since I am considering person as creator of the element, is it right to write

```
let neighbours (turtle-set person in-link-neighbors with [breed = breed1] of person)
          ask neighbours
          [set my-list fput new_elem my-list]
```

And if it would be correct, how can I add a new element as "New element" to the list, taking into account its attribute for further consideration.

For example: `set my-list fput (list attribute1 attribute2) of elements my-list`) returns me list of values like `(0.134531 0.14141) (0.91844 0.42176)` ... Any suggestions to have something nicer to see but with the same information? I will need to keep track of this values in the next steps.

I hope you can shed some light on what I am doing incorrectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Val, here's some working code that creates a new element and updates everyone's my-list.

It's probably not exactly what you wanted but I hope it provides some help anyway.
You didn't include all the info on breeds and who owns what so I punted.

I broke up more complex commands into multiple shorter ones in order to debug what was going on and where it was breaking down.     I added some print statements.

If you load this up, run setup, and hit "go" once,  you can see agents in a network linked up with their "who" numbers besides them so you can easily inspect the ones you
want.   Values of my-list are also printed out in the command section.

Two more iterations of the "go" step should verify that they are outputting what you wanted.

I didn't know whether you wanted new_elem to be just local to the create_elements section, of if you wanted it globally available, so I put comments in both places.

I hope this helps!  There are more comments in the code itself. Note especially that you **must** initialize my-list as an empty list, or it **will** default to the number zero, and your fput statement will fail with a comment about expecting a list and finding zero.

```
globals [   
     ;;new_elem   ;; might be needed as a global ??
  ]

;; ///////////////////// note that there is no breed required called "people"

breed  [ elements element]
breed  [ breed1 lion ]
breed  [ breed2 tiger ]

;; ///////////////////// i punted on which entity owned "function1 and function2

breed1-own [ attribute function1 function2 my-list]
breed2-own [ attribute function1 function2 my-list]

to setup
  clear-all

  ;; make some turtles with breed = breed1 (say, red lions)
   create-breed1 2 [ set size 2 set shape "circle"   set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   ]

  ;; make some turtles with breed = breed2  (say, green tigers)
  create-breed2 2 [ set size 2 set shape "circle"   set color green
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   ]

  ;; //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ;;  NOTE!!!   If you don't initialize my-list to an empty LIST type,
  ;;            fput will generate an error when you try to fput a new element onto it

  ;; this is ugly but fast:
  ask breed1 [create-links-with other breed1
    set my-list [] ]
  ask breed1 [create-links-with breed2
    set my-list [] ]

  ask breed2 [create-links-with other breed2
    set my-list [] ]
  ask breed2 [create-links-with breed1
    set my-list [] ]

  ask turtles [set label who]  ;; ///////////////////////// for debugging

 ;; set new_elem nobody          ;; this could be a global so it can persist 
                                 ;; outside create_element, in which case 
                                 ;; initilize it here

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  create_elements
  tick
end

to create_elements    


  ;; declare the local variables, all agent-sets of some type

  let new_elem nobody  ;; declare this locally if we don't need to persist it
                       ;; outside the create_elements context
                       ;; and remove the declaration in [ globals ]
                       ;; and initializtion in setup

  let personx nobody
  let xx-neighbors nobody

  ;; do just this creation here in order to see what's going on more easily
  ;; than combining multiple operations into a long complex command


  create-elements 1 [ set new_elem self ]
   type "new element is this agentset " show new_elem

  set personx one-of turtles with [breed = breed1 or breed = breed2]

  ifelse [breed = breed1] of personx
     [ ;; if it is breed1
       ask personx [
       set attribute random-float 1
       set function1 (1 + attribute)
       ]
    ]
    [  ;; else, it must be  breed2
       ask personx [
       set attribute random-float 1
       set function2 (1 - attribute)
       ]
     ]

    ;;//////////////////////////////////////// for debugging
    type "the personx we defined above is " print personx

    ask personx [set xx-neighbors (turtle-set self in-link-neighbors  )]

    if-else xx-neighbors != nobody    ;; If it has any members, which should
                                      ;; always be true since we added self to the set
    [
       ask xx-neighbors  
        [
          set my-list fput  new_elem  my-list

          ;; ////////////////////////////////////for debugging
          type "here's the resulting my-list: " show my-list
        ]
    ]
    [ print "ERROR didn't find any neighbors or self" ]

end
```

Comment: Thank you for you help and answer Wade. I would have a question, if I may, as it is not completely clear to me when I should use global variables and local. In my code, attribute is associated to the element created, but the action to create this element should be done but one of the two breeds. Then, attribute should be a breed1/2-own or an element-own? About the new_elem,I would like to track it throughout the simulation, changing it depending on the distance of nodes,so it would be important to save it in the list and pick it up based on some criteria to define.Should it be global or local?